# Vertical Black Bars, Aspect Ratio Problem. NEED A FIX

Tags: premiere, adobe

Heres the problem.

When exporting in Adobe Premiere CS5, there is an output tab. Once clicked it should show me what the video will look like when its exported but this is not the case and even when uploaded to youtube it isn't correct. Here are some screen shots to prove what I am talking about. I should add, when looking at the exported version. I have even checked off aspect correction to off and on then on and off. Also, matching sequence settings doesn't work either.

Ouput Tab

[image]

Presets

[image]

Clip Settings (Proves its actually in 480)

[image]

Finally here it is after its exported, how do I fix this. Many suggestions would help. THANKS!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have set the wrong pixel aspect ratio (that has nothing do with the aspect ratio of your video resolution). Notice how you're source footage (the mpg file) has a pixel aspect ratio of 1.21 but you export it with a pixel aspect ratio of 0.91. Also your sequence is set to a pixel aspect ratio of 0.91 (that value in parenthesis next to your resolution in the export settings where the source specs are listed).

Change your sequence settings to the same pixel aspect ratio as your source (1.21 or simple the widescreen setting in the drop down menu), aswell as in your export settings. Though your might wanna export with a square pixel aspect ratio of 1:1 which is what youtube prefers. You will have to change the resolution for that though.

Comment: Minor issue, I believe the Standard 4:3 actually is refering to the pixel aspect used in 4:3 DV which is either .91 or 1.09 depending on NTSC or Pal, not 1.33 which is the ratio used for HD anamorphic widescreen.  1.21 is what should be used, which is NTSC DV widescreen.  [Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/aspect-ratios.html)

Comment: Right I forgot about that, I just divided the aspect ratio.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have different aspect ratios on your various source files based on the appearance of the video.  You will need to adjust for this which will also mean needing to crop some of your video files to fit properly.

You need to choose a target resolution.  I'd recommend starting with square pixels if you intend it for web distribution or the appropriate DV standard if you intend it for DVD (either NTSC Widescreen or regular).  You then need to interpret everything at the appropriate format so that it displays properly despite whatever scaling is applied and then apply positions as necessary to get it to fill the screen.

This is non-trivial and may take a bit of time to get right.  While it will reduce the quality some, you may also want to consider resizing and altering the pixel aspect ratio of each clip individually before editing as that may be easier overall to keep track of what you are doing.